# Past Simple + Present Simple

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know which of the following sentences is correct and, if possible, why one is correct and other isn't.

1. He taught me how the world works.
2. He taught me how the world worked.

Comment: Both can be correct, assuming that the world still works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

*Both are correct*. All the sentences can mean the same, but the second can also imply that now the world does not work the way it did in the past.